# What is the meaning of orphanRemoval in entity class JPA

Tags: jpa-2.0

Hye. Im a java newbie. I just want to clarify something. I have an Aptype.java that is entity class in JPA and i have this set up :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "apType", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<ApTypeOption> apTypeOptions;
```

What is oprhanRemoval = true mean?

Comment: When asking about a well-documented topic, please refer to the documentation and narrow the question down to what exactly is unclear about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreeing with kostja's comment. Nevertheless a simple explanation here for instance:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqxy/